# Sql query for date range for individual date values

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

My question is specific to my problem at hand, so I would try to explain the scenario first. I need to write a sql query. Following is the scenario:

**Table columns for table1:**

```
effective_date  
expire_date  
amount_value  
state_id  
amount_entry_type
```

**Case 1, Input values:**

```
input_date
```

I've achieved it using following sql query:
Sample Query:

```
select state_id, sum(amount) 
from table1 
where state_id=3 and (input_date between effective_date and expiry_date) 
group by state_id;
```

**My Question:**
Now I've a date range and I wish to achieve the above for all the dates between date range.

**Input values 2:**

```
input_start_date  
input_end_date
```

**Expected Output:**

Find the sum of `amount_value grouped by states where input_date between effective and expire_date for input_date between input_start_date and input_end_date`.

So the query would give following sample result for date range `2016-07-07` and `2016-07-08` :

```
state         amount_sum     date
California    100            2016-07-07
Florida       200            2016-07-08
```

I'm using postgres as database and django for querying and processing the result.
**Options:**

```
1. Fetch all the data and process using python.  
2. Loop over given date range and fire the query above as:

for input_date in date_range(input_start_date, input_end_date):
    //Execute above query
```

Both above solutions might have performance issues so I was wondering if I could achieve it using single sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed do this with a single query, using the `generate_series()` set-returning-function to make the list of days. If you are sure that all dates have corresponding rows for the state then you can you use a regular `JOIN`, otherwise use a `LEFT JOIN` as below.

```
SELECT state_id, sum(amount), dt AS "date"
FROM generate_series(input_start_date, input_end_date, '1 day') dates(dt)
LEFT JOIN table1 ON state_id = 3 AND (dt BETWEEN effective_date AND expiry_date) 
GROUP BY state_id, dt;
```